# parse-server returns wrong Date format

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

When querying on Parse server this is the result:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "BMRfgFD1SU",
            "username": "demo@user.com",
            "createdAt": "2017-04-13T16:52:37.661Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-04-13T16:52:37.661Z",
            "ACL": {
                "*": {
                    "read": true
                },
                "BMRfgFD1SU": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that the date format now is a String however it should be like:

```
{
 "__type": "Date",
 "iso": "2015-03-01T15:59:11-07:00"
}
```

Comment: interesting... I can reproduce.  I couldn't find anywhere in the doc that mentions that the special fields createAt and updatedAt are treated differently than any other date field.  Do you know if this was different in parse.com than in parse-server?  My user created date fields are displaying as you expect, just not createdAt and updatedAt.

Comment: The createdAt, updatedAt look valid to me, according to the docs: http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse date type is able to parse various different formats.  parse-server itself uses a specific format, and wherever you're setting the date elsewhere is using a different format is all. If you need more consistency, add a helper function to enforce / update dates to a specific format, and call it anywhere you take a date as input to a cloud function and in the beforeSave trigger of any class that has a date type field.

Your other option is to make sure anywhere you send / use dates from your clients format the data properly, but this is less future proof.

Edit - I recommend in your validation / formatting you adhere to the format of created/updatedAt, as you are not able to modify those values set by Parse-Server.